# Not expected value of pointer at C

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have such code:

```
int *x[2];
int var0 = 10;
int var1 = 20;
int var2 = 30;
x[0] = &var0;
x[1] = &var1;
x[2] = &var2;

cout << "var0 is equal to: " << *x[0] << endl;
```

---

```
var0 is equal to: 32767
```

What I'm expecting:

- I've initialized array of pointers with 3 items
- Assigned some values to 3 variables
- Assigned addresses of this variables to items of array of pointers
- Now I'm expecting: `*x[0] = 10, *x[1] = 20, *x[2] = 30`, but as you can see from example `*x[0] == 32767`. Why?

Comment: `x[2]` doesn't exist; you've just invoked **undefined behaviour** by writing to it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Most likely it exists, though only as a reincarnation of buddha in the form of memory allocated for the program stack :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int *x[2];
```

declares an array of 2 pointers.  Valid indexes for this array are [0..1].  The line

```
x[2] = &var2;
```

writes beyond the end of the array.  This has undefined consequences but it sounds like `&var0 == x[2]` so you're over-writing `var0`, setting it to `var2`'s address.

If you want to assign 3 pointer values, you need an array with three elements - `int *x[3];`

Answer (score 2):

you've created an array with 2 elements, but you're writing to 3 elements - that's not going to help your issue